# Pacman ai project - Suitable of combination of step cost and heuristic

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics, pacman

As part of a project, I am trying to implement A* within the context of a pacman game (see UC Berkley pacman ai project). There are no ghosts or capsules, only a maze and the 'fruit'. I am having trouble, however, understanding the relationship between my heuristic function and my cost function.

As per the project, when defining the search problem, we need to specify a step cost that derives from: 
`score = -Nb Steps + 10*NbOfEatenDots + 200*NbOfEatenGhosts + (-500*isLoss) + (500*isWin)`
This cost is supposed to be always positive and so, for simplicity, I have decided to take: `1.5 - (0.5*AteAFoodDot)`. I have ignored ghosts and capsules since they do not exist and I have given a preferential score for moves tht end up eating a dot. I have also ignored steps that result in a loss (since they do not exist) and steps that result in a win state.

Now as far as the A* algorithm itself is concerned, we have to implement a cost function and a heuristic function of our own:

As a cost function I have chosen: `Cost = sum(step costs to current state)` and as a heuristic: `h = Manhattan distance between pacman and the dot closest to him + manhattan distance of this dot and another dot that is furthest away from it, as long as it exists`, which is an admissible heuristic. I have also implemented this heuristic using real maze distances instead of manhattan distances, but this seemed too time consuming for mazes with many food dots.

Now if I have understood correctly if `g(n)` is my cost function and `h(n)` my heuristic, I must always have: `g(n to goal) >= h(n)` so that A* always returns an optimal path and the closest the values of `g` and `h` for a node n, the less nodes will be expanded.

In this respect, is it not in my interest to ignore how the score is computed, ignore the fact that a step results in eating a food dot or not and simply take `step_cost = 1` for all steps?

This is how I obtain the best results with respect to computation time and nodes expanded, but ignoring the cost function of the game seems wrong.

Could someone clarify this for me? Is it a matter of rpeference/choice or is there an objective correct answer/best approach?